# GCP App Engine 502 error - failed_to_pick_backend

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, service, streamlit

The Web App was deployed and working fine for a week, until the health check status failed (The VM instance is unreachable, or the app probed by the health check is unreachable, or the app didn't respond to the health check probe before timing out)

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Nothing changed and the app was deployed a week ago, what could be causing the error 502? Seems to be related with the load balancer

```
cacheDecision: [2]
remoteIp: "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
statusDetails: "failed_to_pick_backend"
```

Comment: Can you share the minimal steps you followed to reproduce? And also `app.yaml`, `load balancer` and `health check` config?